# Can i make my camera follow a mesh and mimic its rotation?

Tags: animation, camera

So i would like to make a short 3D animation from first person perspective and I want the camera to follow the location of the head on my mesh as well as its rotation. Is it possible or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can set the armature's headbone as the camera's parent.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks dude!